# .Net Core 6 + AWS Lambda unable to handle base64 data in request body

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, aws-lambda, devops

I publish a .net core minimal API to lambda using VS 2022 Publish to lambda tool. The API accept a base64 string of a image that need to upload to S3. The problem is the lambda fails with (504) gateway timeout error when I invoke the request from Postman. The endpoint works fine if `photo` parameter is empty. Here is my lambda hosting in `Program.cs` file.

```
builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi);
```

The request body from Postman

```
{
    "photo": "/9j/4AAQSkZ.....",
    "ext": "png"
}
```

Content of `server.template` file

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
  "Parameters": {},
  "Conditions": {},
  "Resources": {
    "AspNetCoreFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "xxx",
        "Runtime": "dotnet6",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambda_FullAccess",
          "AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
        ],
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          },
          "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Content of `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` .

```
{
    "Information" : [
        "...."
    ],
    "profile"     : "default",
    "region"      : "ap-southeast-1",
    "configuration" : "Release",
    "s3-prefix"     : "xxx/",
    "template"      : "serverless.template",
    "template-parameters" : "",
    "s3-bucket"           : "xxx",
    "stack-name"          : "xxx"
}
```

Comment: [You should not post code (or errors/exceptions, logs, configuration, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7450780)

Comment: Are you still looking for answer?